# Return Distinct Values Where One Column Is The Same But One Column Different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to return results in TSQL where it ***only*** displays addresses where there are multiple names. The tricky part has been there are multiple duplicates already in this table... so the Having Count variations that I've tried do not work because they all have a count greater than one. So I have not been able to easily distinguish unique names that have the same address. The solution illustrated below is what I would like to produce... and I have but my solution is a sad last ditched effort within Access where I ended up using a query with three sub queries to get the results:

```
Address             Name
101 1st Ave         Brian Wood
101 1st Ave         Amy Wood
101 1st Ave         Adam Wood
555 5th St          Sarah Parker
555 5th St          Parker Corp.
```

Sample Data Looks Like this:

```
Address             Name
101 1st Ave         Brian Wood
101 1st Ave         Brian Wood
101 1st Ave         Brian Wood
101 1st Ave         Amy Wood
101 1st Ave         Adam Wood
555 5th St          Sarah Parker
555 5th St          Sarah Parker
555 5th St          Sarah Parker
555 5th St          Parker Corp.
```

I've been trying to get this for hours... I know their is a much simpler way to do this but as it's been a 16 hour day and it's 2:00 am I just can't get my head around it.

Here is an example of my best TSQL results... it does the trick but it bumps it into two different columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name, t2.Name, t1.Address
FROM tblLeads t1
  JOIN tblLeads t2 ON t1.Address = t2.Address 
WHERE t1.Name <> t2.Name
ORDER BY t1.Address
```

Comment: Show what you have tried. Also, you have shown the desired result, but what was the sample data?

Comment: So to be clear, you want to display rows where multiple names are present for 1 address (in the example all the addresses)?

Comment: in the sample data you use Address and Name, in the example you use Street and LastName ?!?

Comment: @TimSchmelter added sample data and what I've tried.

Comment: @NickyvV Yes... that's correct

Comment: @PavelGatnar... Yes, your correct... good eye and my apologies. I cleaned up the names in my illustration. My code post contained actual field names (which naming convention I don't agree with... but it is what it is.) Sorry I should have made both the same to avoid confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a `GROUP` with `COUNT(Distinct Name) > 1` to get Address with more than 1 unique name, and then do a select distinct with a filter on the above grouped Addresses like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Address,Name
From Table1
WHERE Address IN (
SELECT Address
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Address
HAVING COUNT(distinct Name) > 1
)
```

Comment: Very Nice... Extra +1 on the COUNT(DISTINCT Name)... I've never seen DISTINCT used in that fashion so it never occured to me to try that... and it was exactly what I needed

Comment: Concise but has an issue with addresses that are `NULL`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cd9b/3/0

Comment: Correct, if the data has addresses with `NULLs`, This sql will exclude such records. Based on OP's data, I don't think that is a concern here.

Comment: WITH t as (SELECT DISTINCT Address,Name
From Table1) SELECT * FROM t WHERE Address IN (SELECT Address FROM t GROUP BY Address HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) would be more efficient

Comment: @PavelGatnar - An even efficient solution is what Tim Schmelter suggested in his answer

Comment: sorry, I didn't see his answer, his solution is optimal

Answer (score 5):

You could use multiple `CTE's` to simplify this task. You first want to clean up your data, so remove all those duplicates, therefore you can use `DISTINCT`. Then use `Count(*)OVER(Partition By Address)` to get the count of rows per `Address`:

```
WITH CleanedData AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT Address, Name
   FROM dbo.tblLeads
),
CTE AS
(
   SELECT Address, Name, 
          cnt = Count(*) OVER (Partition By Address)
   FROM CleanedData
)
SELECT Address, Name
FROM CTE
WHERE cnt > 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ca1d/3/0)</kbd>

By the way, this works also if `Address` has `null` values: <kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cd9b/1/0)</kbd> (as opposed to [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cd9b/3/0)).

Answer (score 2):

Use `EXISTS` to verify same addresses but other name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.LastName, t1.Street
FROM tblLeads t1
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from tblLeads t2
              where t1.Street = t2.Street
                and t1.LastName <> t2.LastName)
ORDER BY t1.Street
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution to Tim's one without CTE:

```
select address, name
from (select t.*, count(*) over(partition by address) as cnt
  from (select distinct address, name from tblLeads) t
) where  cnt > 1
```